# Viewport gets ignored by iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, width, viewport

After having searched the whole afternoon for a solution online I am asking you here. The main difference of my viewport-problem from other problems mentioned on StackOverflow is that I only access it in Portrait mode (so no rotating or Landscape mode). Here is my problem:

I created a website containing as its basic structure three columns: 44pt- (div-element), 232pt- (input-element) and 44pt-width (div-element) respectively. So my maximum page width is equal to 320pt, the height of all elements is until now <250pt.

If I now render the page on the iOS Simulator (via XCode on Mac), which should be identical to an iPhone's behaviour, it does not scale the page correctly. I tried already the following options:

```
[no meta-tag]
```

shows approximately 240% of width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
```

shows approximately 70% of width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />
```

focus on the first div which has "width=44pt"

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0;" />
```

shows approximately 70% of width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320;" />
```

focus on the first div which has "width=44pt"

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0;" />
```

shows approximately 70% of width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

shows approximately 70% of width

The result stays the same: The web page is once too small (too much zoomed out), once too big (too much zoomed in). Only by tweaking the "initial-scale"-value to around .75 I get approximately the desired result.

What is my error for the iPhone-Safari? Which arguments should I use for the meta-viewport tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution quite some time ago and thought maybe someone else is interested one day: Instead of defining the sizes in my css-file in points ("pt") I now use pixels ("px"). Rendering is now as desired.